# A problem with the "require" keyword not finding the file to load

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I have a problem with the "require" keyword in ruby, I just downloaded a gem using:

```
gem install thegem
```

And when I tried running an example I received the following error:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- 
    ./thegem/some/path (LoadError)
```

In the code where the problem is:

```
needs_to_load = a_class
require "gem/some/path/#{needs_to_load}"
```

I'm a Ruby noob learning my way around and am not sure what this is, a google search didn't help but revealed that it may be due to needing a relative path, however changing the 2nd line to the following did not help:

```
require "./gem/some/path/#{needs_to_load}"
```

I'm using RVM with the following ruby version: `ruby-1.9.2-head`.

(p.s. sorry if this has been asked before I didn't see anything for it in the related questions field)

[Edit: appending the output of 'rvm info' and 'gem env' per Tin Man's request below]

```
$ gem env

RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2010-08-18 patchlevel 0) [i386-darwin9.8.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-darwin-9
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head
     - /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/

$ rvm info

ruby-1.9.2-head:

  system:
    uname:       "Darwin macintosh 10.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.5.0: Fri Nov  5 23:20:39 PDT 2010; root:xnu-1504.9.17~1/RELEASE_I386 i386"
    zsh:         "zsh 4.3.9 (i386-apple-darwin10.0)"
    bash:        "GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.0.1 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.2p0"
    date:         "2010-08-18"
    platform:     "i386-darwin9.8.0"
    patchlevel:   "2010-08-18 revision 29034"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29034) [i386-darwin9.8.0]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head"
    ruby:         "/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/git/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head"
    GEM_PATH:     "/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global"
    BUNDLE_PATH:  "/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head"
    IRBRC:        "/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Comment: To specify relative path, you need `require_relative` since 1.9.2. Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005013/ruby-strange-error - is it what you ask? Or just try to add `require 'rubygems'` before your `require 'thegem'`.

Comment: thanks for the reply Nakilon - may I ask you though, if I download several libraries that have this problem, does this mean I have to go through them and either require_relative "/gem/some/path..." or do I have to add require "rubygems" to every source file that has this problem? Is there some sort of compatibility mode?

Comment: If `require 'rubygems'` solves your problem, I think it's normal to add this line into some top script of your program.

Comment: Ruby 1.9.2 automatically does a `require 'rubygems'`. 1.8.7 needs it though.

Comment: What's the name of the gem in question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a normal `gem install somegem`, then you should be able to `require 'somegem'`, without any path added to the name of the gem. `require_relative` is useful for gems and modules that are installed somewhere out of the normal Ruby search paths, such as ones you've written and embedded in a `lib` directory immediately below the calling script's directory.

Use `gem env` and append its output to your original question by editing it, which will help us determine if it's a pathing issue. Because you are using RVM, your gem path should be pointing into your `~/.rvm` folder. If you do `rvm info` it will also give you path info, so compare the output of those two commands to see if they are consistent.

Comment: I've added the otuput of those commands, it appears as if they are pointing to ~/.rvm. The 'require' is called from a file in the .rvm path: from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
 from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/project/lib/path/class.rb:244:in `method'

Comment: @Folken, one thing I see is your rvm version is out of date. As of this morning we're on v.1.1.6, whereas you're on 1.0.1. Given how fast Wayne Seguin moves, that's a large number of changes. See if your rvm knows how to `rvm get head` to update itself.

Comment: Here's what I think is happening. The gem you're using appears to have been written for Ruby 1.8+, not 1.9+. Ruby's search path changed in 1.9 which is why they added `require_relative`. Try switching rvm to use your system Ruby: `rvm use system` should do it, or use `rvm install 1.8.7; rvm use 1.8.7` and run your app. Your system Ruby probably won't have the gem you need so you might need to add it, so installing 1.8.7 and the needed gems into your ~/.rvm sandbox might be safer/better/wiser.

Comment: It's correct for the current rvm. I think the old command was something like `rvm update --self`.