# require not working while writing a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

i am trying to write a gem using bundler (following ryan's railcast - 245)
i followed everything described by ryan. I also added 4 ruby files in the lib folder to learn about how require works with different gem.

i thought it will automatically require those rb files put in lib folder.
but unfortunately while i test it it throws an error saying 
no such file to load lib/myclass.rb
This what my lorem.rb looks like.

```
require 'lorem/version'  
require 'lorem/myclass'  

Module Lorem  
.....  
end
```

What am i missing ? can any body tell how gem require works ?

NB : I use to do it with echoe and it works . but when i am using bulder, gemspec and all i simply dont understand why its not loading files .

My gem Spec file

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)
require "lorem/version"

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = "lorem"
  s.version     = Lorem::VERSION
  s.authors     = ["My Name"]
  s.email       = ["me@domain.com"]
  s.homepage    = ""
  s.summary     = %q{learing bundler gem}
  s.description = %q{Learing bundler gem}

  s.rubyforge_project = "lorem"

  s.files         = `git ls-files`.split("\n")
  s.test_files    = `git ls-files -- {test,spec,features}/*`.split("\n")
  s.executables   = `git ls-files -- bin/*`.split("\n").map{ |f| File.basename(f) }
  s.require_paths = ["lib"]

  #s.add_development_dependency "rspec"
  #s.add_development_dependency "supermodel"
end
```

thanks in advance

Comment: where does this myclass.rb come from? it is not there in the ryan's railcast - 245 description. Try if the file exists and also try my_class.rb

Comment: myclass.rb is a file which i added in lib/lorem folder. i tried to write the code there in myclass.rb and use it in lorem.rb by requiring it . but it didnt work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516533/a-problem-with-the-require-keyword-not-finding-the-file-to-load

Comment: when i inspect the gems folder i see only version.rb in the lib folder. why is that it doesnt copy other ruby files in the lib when doing rake install ? should i need to mention it explicitly anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

In your gemspec, try replacing `$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)` with:

```
$:.unshift('lib')
```

Comment: i am not doing testing . infact i tried it in a rails project directly  by giving gem 'mygem'

Comment: @KrishnaprasadVarma could you post your gemspec?

Comment: i have added gemspec to the question.

Comment: @KrishnaprasadVarma, I have updated my answer based on your gemspec. Give it a try, and let me know if it works. Good luck!

Comment: i tried rake build, rake install after updating it. when i did ls /Users/kpvarma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/lorem-0.0.1.old/lib/lorem/, i could see only version.rb only .

Comment: http://mlomnicki.com/ruby/rubygems/2011/01/22/jeweler-vs-bundler.html in this blog peter says The major drawback of bundler is that you have to add all the files manualy to the *.gemspec file.. what does this means?

Answer (score 0):

Finally Cracked it.

```
lib = File.expand_path('../lib/', __FILE__)  
$:.unshift lib unless $:.include?(lib)
```

and giving the following inside

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|

  ...
  s.files        = Dir.glob("{bin,lib}/**/*")
  ...

end
```

I got this hint from http://yehudakatz.com/2010/04/02/using-gemspecs-as-intended/

Comment: Does anybody knows why rake install doesnt copy all the ruby codes in lib folder but only those mentioned in s.files ?

Comment: Because that's the point of `s.files`: it is the list of things to include in the gem

Comment: @KrishnaprasadVarma glad to hear you were able to resolve your issue.